# The Rest Client in Pentaho Kettle is truncating the result

Tags: rest, truncate, kettle

I have developed the following transformation:

[image]

It almost works perfectly, however the result of the Rest Client is being truncated.

I created a simple Web Service to test this process and it returns the following JSON:

[image]

I output the result of the Web Service to a field called **result**.

[image]

When the previewed the Rest Client shows that field9 and the closing bracket are missing from the **result** field.

Is there a size limit to the output field? Is there a way to change the size of the field? Am I using the Rest Client correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the field was not being truncated. field9 and the closing bracket were there all along. Only the UI was preventing me from from seeing the whole field. I discovered this when I copied the field from the UI and pasted it in a text editor.